# Blank maps rendered while using Expo 46 and react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, expo

Maps are rendered empty while using Expo SDK 46, it was working perfectly in previous SDK versions, my Google API Keys are set and all required APIs are enabled. It just shows a blank map with the Google Logo

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~46.0.7",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "^11.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-check-box": "2.1.7",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.31.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also facing the same problem with Expo SDK 46, The maps rendered are blank with only the Google Logo. Migrating back to Expo 44 was the only option which worked for me